# Download PDF from bytes coming as string

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, pdf, pdfmake

I am getting bytes as string from API response:

```
$scope.image = 
"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"
```

Now I want to convert it back to image and then download it as PDF.

The following is not working:

```
window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + $scope.image);
```

I also tried using pdfMake but that doesn't work either:

```
 var dlnk = document.getElementById('dwnldLnk');
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('dwnldLnk'), {
                        onrendered: function (canvas) {
                            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                            var docDefinition = {
                                content: [{
                                    image: data,
                                    width: 500
                                }]
                            };
                            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Roster.pdf");
                        }
                    });
```

And the HTML client side has the div as:

```
<div id="dwnldLnk" style="display:none;">
     {{image}}
    </div>
```

On Server Side this is the code to store bytes:

```
        String html = "<h1>Hello, world.</h1>";

        JLabel label = new JLabel(html);
        label.setSize(200, 120);

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        {
            // paint the html to an image
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            label.paint(g);
            g.dispose();
        }

        // get the byte array of the image (as jpeg)
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);          
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // these bytes are stored in bytea column in postgres database
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: image.data:application/pdf;base64, will not work. create a pdf with "data:image/png;base64," as image in pdfMake,
check this url:
https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/examples/images.js

Comment: still not working. Getting error- "Failed to load PDF document"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your image is not showing correctly inside pdf i checked with other image base64 strings and they work well. So you also need to check how you convert the image to base64 string. What worked for me is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <button id="download">download</button>

<script>
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
    document.body.appendChild(image);

    download.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(image, 'JPG', 0, 0);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
    }, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although it worked but the rendered PDF is HTML code. It is showing "<h1>Hello, world.</h1>" instead of Hello, world. How to render the HTML out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this code in angularjs. The html `<h1>` and `</h1>` looks like part of the generated image in java. The following code has downloaded the pdf with the image successfully.

```
var main = myApp.controller("main", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    /*
    Include the following two lines in index.html head

     <script src='build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
     <script src='build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>

     After that in your angularjs controller you can write the following lines to implement a function.
     getPdf in the controller scope. This can be attached to a button click using ng-click and it will
     download the pdf with the image.

     eg.

     <div ng-controller="main">
     <button ng-click="getPdf()">Get PDF</button>
     </div>
     */

    $scope.image = "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";

    $scope.getPdf = function(){

        var imageContentDefinition = {
            content: [
                {
                    image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + $scope.image
                }
            ]};
        pdfMake.createPdf(imageContentDefinition).download("yourpdf.pdf");
    };

}]);
```